# C# WPF Retrieve Image from SQL Server database, byte to image

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, image

So I have these codes that will get me the user information.

**NOTE**: the commented lines are the stuff that I have already tried.

Code:

```
    public UserInfo GetUserCredentials(string usernameParameter, string passwordParameter)
    {
        UserInfo getInfo = new UserInfo();

        try
        {
            accessToDatabase.OpeningDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Users where Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = accessToDatabase.Command(query);

            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", usernameParameter);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordParameter);
            SqlDataReader oReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            byte[] pictureIdByte;
            Image pictureIdImg = null;

            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                getInfo.Username = oReader["Username"].ToString();
                getInfo.Password = oReader["Password"].ToString();
                getInfo.Role = oReader["Role"].ToString();
                getInfo.Firstname = oReader["Firstname"].ToString();
                getInfo.Lastname = oReader["Lastname"].ToString();
                getInfo.Status = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["Status"]);
                getInfo.Gender = oReader["Gender"].ToString();
                getInfo.Birthday = oReader["Birthday"].ToString();
                getInfo.Email = oReader["Email"].ToString();
                getInfo.Address = oReader["Address"].ToString();
                getInfo.City = oReader["City"].ToString();
                getInfo.Country = oReader["Country"].ToString();
                getInfo.Mobilenumber = oReader["Mobile"].ToString();

                pictureIdByte = (byte[])(oReader["PictureID"]);

                if (pictureIdByte == null)
                {
                    getInfo.PictureID = pictureIdImg;
                }
                else
                {
                    //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pictureIdByte);
                    //getInfo.PictureID.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

                    //var pictureIdVar = new BitmapImage();
                    //using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(pictureIdByte))
                    //{
                    //    memStream.Position = 0;
                    //    pictureIdVar.BeginInit();
                    //    pictureIdVar.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
                    //    pictureIdVar.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    //    pictureIdVar.UriSource = null;
                    //    pictureIdVar.StreamSource = memStream;
                    //    pictureIdVar.EndInit();
                    //}
                    //pictureIdVar.Freeze();
                    //getInfo.PictureID.Source = pictureIdVar;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            accessToDatabase.ClosingDataBase();
        }
        return getInfo;
    }
```

AND I have this main window where it has an image which I dropped and drag from the xaml design. And using the code behind, I tried setting the source like this but whenever I am trying to log-in it is giving me an error of:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

`MyThesisProject.Model.UserInfo.PictureID.get` returned null.

Here is the code behind of the main window xaml:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(UserInfo userLoginDetails)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imgTest.Source = userLoginDetails.PictureID.Source;
    }
}
```

I do not know where did I go wrong, I tried using the commented lines but still the same error of null.

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: You literally _set_ `PictureID` to null when no bytes are retrieved though... was that `pictureIdImg` meant to be a default image instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have an `Image` element in your UserInfo class.

Change the type of the `PictureID` property to ImageSource

```
public class UserInfo
{
    ...
    public ImageSource PictureID { get; set; } 
    ...
}
```

and set its value like this:

```
if (pictureIdByte != null)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(pictureIdByte))
    {
        getInfo.PictureID = BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
                                BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

In your MainWindow constructor, set the Image's Source like this:

```
imgTest.Source = userLoginDetails.PictureID;
```