# How to display an image inside a imagebox that is stored inside a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, image

I have a bunch of images stored in a SQL Server database and I want to be able to display these images once the WPF application loads in. I have been doing a lot of research and the closest thing to solving this problem is the code I have found below but I'm not even sure if that is correct and it doesn't work so far.

Code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-3SCT3MQA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RareMantis;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("SELECT GameCover FROM tblGames WHERE GameID = 1", sqlConnection));
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
            data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["GameCover"]);
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);            
            // GameCover1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem); 
            //              ^ this word(Image) is causing an error 
        }
}
```

```
 <Image x:Name="GameCover1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="36,314,0,-1.6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="411"/>
```

Comment: What type is GameCover1? What is error message?

Comment: @MarcBernier Type 'Image' error  is "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no accessible extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 'Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

Comment: Do you have an element in your GameCover1 form that is an Image? What is that property's name?

Comment: 'image' is deprecated, and you are strongly advised to update your schema to use the varbinary(max) type instead. You can just do an ALTER COLUMN in place, and it will "just work". This doesn't help answer your question, but it's important. The 'image" type will not be supported in future SQL Server versions, and isn't supported on Azure SQL.

Comment: @MarcBernier GameCover1 is the name of the element Image.

Comment: GameCover1.Source = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem) ?

Comment: @MarcBernier if i do that i get this Error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' "

Comment: @MarcBernier could there be an issuse with the code being in `public mainwindow()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error you mention:

> 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'Image'

occures because the WPF control [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image) does not have a property named "Image". Instead, you need to use the [`Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.source) property.

MarcBernier was on the right track trying to convert the binary data from SQL into a usable image, but the method he provided is for Winforms, not WPF. Since the two aren't compatible you get the second error from the comments:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

As it points out, you need an [`ImageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource) object. After a bit of research, I came across [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843128/c-sharp-wpf-retrieve-image-from-sql-server-database-byte-to-image) with an answer that should also help you. Try this:

```
GameCover1.Image = BitmapFrame.Create(mem, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

As a final note, pmbAustin is correct that you should no longer be using the SQL `image` type. This solution should still work after switching over to `varbinary(MAX)`.